# how to add dynamic tooltip text with leaflet.draw?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I use leaflet.draw plugin to add some shapes to map, but i need to change the information (static text) of the tooltip when the user move the cursor (mousemove) on edit mode or on adding some vertex.

How can i intercept this event, something like

```
 map.on('draw:cursor-move', function (e, latlng, options) {
    ....
 })
```

Also, I tried to extend the update text function and update position, but i need also the mousemove event, action or shape type and the latlng position.